# Can't run rails after changing the ruby global version to 2.6.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, rbenv

I am getting this:

```
rbenv: rails: command not found

The `rails' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.6.1
  2.6.2
```

I have already tried running:

```
gem install bundler 
rbenv rehash
gem install rails
rbenv rehash
```

In my global environment:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.6.4p104 (2019-08-28 revision 67798) [x86_64-linux]
rbenv -v
rbenv 1.1.2-2-g4e92322
```

Comment: What is the output of `ruby -v` in the rails project folder? you might have the ruby version set in the Gemfile...

Comment: In the ruby folder the output is `ruby 2.6.4p104 (2019-08-28 revision 67798) [x86_64-linux]` , in the gem file  ` ruby "2.6.4"`

Comment: `gem install bundler` and then `bundle install` (to install rails and dependencies set in the Gemfile) should work

Comment: Hi, I've done that but I keep getting `rbenv: rails: command not found

The `rails' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.6.1
  2.6.2`

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/issues/73